# Problem adding a tab to the user menu

Tags: routes

I created a panel page using the Panels module, **Contact list** at the path `messages/contact-list`.

The Privatemsg module causes several tabs (Inbox, Sent messages, All messages) to be displayed across the top of pages with path `messages`.  I am attempting to add an additional tab that links to my Panels page, **Contact list**.

Based on the code in privatemsg.module for the "Sent messages" tab:

```
  $items['messages/sent'] = array(
    'title'            => 'Sent messages',
    'page callback'    => 'privatemsg_list_page',
    'page arguments'   => array('sent'),
    'file'             => 'privatemsg.pages.inc',
    'file path'        => drupal_get_path('module', 'privatemsg'),
    'access callback'  => 'privatemsg_user_access',
    'type'             => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight'           => -12,
    'menu_name'        => 'user-menu',
  );
```

I added this code to `hook_menu()` in a custom module:

```
  $items['messages/contact-list'] = array(
    'title'            => 'Contact List',
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_goto',
    'page arguments'    => array('messages/contact-list'),
    'access callback'  => 'privatemsg_user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('read privatemsg'),
    'type'             => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight'           => 10,
    'menu_name'        => 'user-menu',
  );
```

However, although this produces no errors, even after clearing the cache multiple times no tab appears anywhere.  I tried moving the code from my custom module into the privatemsg module to no effect.  I've looked at the documentation for [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) but it still isn't clear to me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: not including `return $items;` was one thing that caused me to face this problem many times :) and I've seen better and more experienced people than me do this too, so I'd suggest that its worth a check, also suggest checking if there is an entry for `messages/contact-list` in the `menu_router` table with the respective arguments to gain some insight.

Comment: I did include `return $items`; there is an entry in the `menu_router` table with `ctools_access_menu` as the access callback and `page_manager_page_execute` as the page callback.  I don't really understand what that means though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your problem is that page manager has already defined a menu entry for that path. Just as well, because the menu item you have created would cause an infinite chain of redirection. You would need to change the path for your panels page to be something different in order for the redirection to work.

But you can simply remove your menu entry altogether and use page manager to define the menu item for the page as a tab under Settings -> Menu. You shouldn't need any extra code to do that.

Comment: I could've swore there was a reason I avoided using the Panels UI, but I was able to do it this way without trouble.  Thanks!